# Get the current class when changing page to display the same background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am finishing up my portfolio, available here: http://www.studioj7.fr

I've made this little extra thing for user, where they can change the background to one of the four seasons. Whenever I click a link, the background comes back to the original one (currently winter). I would like to make it such that once one background is clicked and set it stays even if the user navigates through the site. I must say I can't make it work even in my head, so any help would be very welcome :-)

Comment: Please attempt to create a working example of your code **in the question itself** so that we can easily test your issue.

Comment: Cookies or local storage are the only real choices

Comment: Seconding what @RobinZigmond is stating, unless you want to move towards a single page app model for your site.

Answer (score 0):

In order for anything to be saved when moving from page to page, it needs to be stored in [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

The best approach to saving something like this would be in local storage as it's longer lasting and doesn't send extra data to the server. For you situation, try saving the data like so when the user selects the background:

```
localStorage.setItem('background', value);
```

Then when you load the page, run a javascript snippet to set the background:

```
//make sure the storage is set
if(localStorage.getItem('background')){
  //apply the data to the background
  document.body.style.background = "url('" + localStorage.getItem('background') + "') no-repeat center";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Jersh, will try to make it work ASAP ! Will keep you posted.

Comment: Hi Jersh, I've tried to implement it between the pages index.html and apropos.html, doesn't seem to work so far.. Maybe I've missed something ?